# iframe/include php file in flash (FLA file)

Tags: php, flash, iframe

How can I load a PHP file into a flash movie ? I need an iframe in Flash or something...

Can anybody post some examples ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a request to a PHP file in Actionscript, and process the data. You can't, as far as I know, render a full HTML file inside a Flash movie. Wouldn't make much sense anyway.

What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to include a html file that runs a Javascript timer.

Comment: @Manny:

You can write timers using actionscript as well. Why would you need to abuse javascript in such a way?

Comment: I would but that's a friend of mine's timer and it's a game timer, I really don't know how to reproduce..

Comment: You can try to make the Javascript timer interact with the flash movie with the JS being in the surrounding HTML or in an IFrame. JS can communicate with Flash and the other way round.